# Sending additional info in post request

Tags: javascript, html, django, forms, datalist

I am trying to implement a form with a "Contacts" datalist, I need to get the `id` number of the contact in order to process it in the db in Django but I don't want the `id` to be shown to the user, I want the datalist to have the "normal" info. The datalist code is the following:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-label" for="contactOptions">Contact:</label>
                <input class="form-control" name="contact" list="contactOptions" placeholder="Type contact">
                <datalist id="contactOptions">
                    {% for contact in contact_options %}
                        <option>
                            {{contact.id}}: {{ contact.info }}
                        </option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </datalist>
            </div>
```

To sum up:

- Want to populate the `datalist` with the info of the contacts except the `id`.
- Need to get the contact `id` when using `request.post` in the views in Django.
- I have a JS file to manipulate the HTML if required.

Answer (score 0):

use hidden fields

```
<input type="hidden" id="contactId" name="contactId" value="{{contact.id}}">
<input type="hidden" id="contactInfo" name="contactInfo" value="{{contact.info }}">
```